# Max aggregation on .keyword field with both string and number values

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a quite common situation on my ElasticSearch: I've an index for products with a barcode field:

```
"barcode": {
               "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "ngram": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "ngram",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                  },
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
```

I need to get the MAX value for the barcode when it's a number: in fact in my index I could have either string values (ie. "`MYBARCODE001245`") or numeric values (i.e. "`1234567890123`"). I need to get the `MAX` value of numeric values only.
In that even possible? I guess I need to change a little bit my schema index because I see the query can't run on my field like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just add another sub-field of type `long` that will ignore malformed values (read non-numeric values), basically like this:

```
  "barcode": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "ngram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ngram",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "numeric": {
        "type": "long",
        "ignore_malformed": true
      }
    }
  }
```

And then you can run a `max` aggregation on the `barcode.numeric` field easily:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "max_barcode": {
      "max": {
        "field": "barcode.numeric"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is something you plan on querying regularly you should definitely change your mapping, if its just a one time thing this should work

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "numbers_only": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "try {Float.parseFloat(doc['barcode.keyword'].value);} catch (NumberFormatException e) {return false} return true"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_bardcode": {
          "max": {
            "script": {
              "source": "Float.parseFloat(doc['barcode.keyword'].value)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Change float to double/int/long whatever depending on which numbers do you expect to have there

Comment: And if you're running 7.11 and above, you should prefer [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) over scripts, but again, as Ron said, only if this is a one-time need. If recurrent and high performance is needed, then you should change your mapping to properly index the data.